# Facebook page feed doesn't work with php file_get_contents()

Tags: php, json, facebook-page

When I go to this url in by browser, it shows me the json feed i expect:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285

When in PHP I do a

```
<?php
print_r(file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285'));
?>
```

I get an html page saying my browser is not supported by facebook and that I should upgrade.   How do I make the file_get_contents return the json feed I'm expecting?

**Additional Notes**  I also tried from bash `wget https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285` and the file I downloaded also has html content saying browser not supported.

Comment: Use curl and set headers for browser. Facebook has check that page should be opened in browser only

Comment: That's a `httpS` link, notice the S for SSL, you'll need to use curl with cacert.pem, or SSL in `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it works for me

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285");
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  echo $data;
```

> As pointed by @Michael Mior, it violates facebook terms. But this is
>   the answer to your question, facebook has a simple check to ensure
>   that page should be opened by browser and thus we are mimicking it by
>   setting `useragent` header.

Comment: Note that this violates Facebook's terms of service.

Comment: @Eugen, copy paste ? I just saw that your code is not working so I set a  `useragent`. Generally all `curl` codes use the same variables, may be this is the reason you see this is your code. Its not my code anyways, take the credit :)

Comment: I just saw your `useragent` is not same as my `useragent` , that clearly says I am not guilty :)

Comment: really you made my day!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Facebook API instead. The [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=237173582992285%2Ffeed) should help get you started as well as the documentation on the [Pages API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

The feeds are designed for use by RSS readers and not for consumption by scripts. You could in theory get around this by changing the `User-Agent` header, but this is against Facebook's [terms of service](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)

> You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise
>   access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots,
>   robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.

Answer (score 2):

To get the public posts of a page you should be using its corresponding connection which is the `feed` connection with any valid `access_token`.

So to get the public feeds of the page you mentioned, you use [`/237173582992285/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=237173582992285/feed). Further more, you can choose to get only the data you need, for example [`/237173582992285?fields=feed.fields(message,type,status_type)`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=237173582992285?fields=feed.fields%28message,type,status_type%29)  would result in something like:

```
{
  "id": "237173582992285",
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "???? ???? ???? :) - ??? <3",
        "type": "photo",
        "status_type": "added_photos",
        "id": "237173582992285_461226513920323",
        "created_time": "2012-11-03T12:46:20+0000"
      },
      {
        "message": "?????? ????? ? ???? ???? ????? ?? ??????? ? ????? ???? ??????? ????? ???? ???????? ????????? :D :D :D - ??? <3",
        "type": "photo",
        "status_type": "added_photos",
        "id": "237173582992285_457876184255356",
        "created_time": "2012-10-26T09:43:01+0000"
      }, 
      ....etc
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/237173582992285/feed?fields=message,type,status_type&limit=25&since=1351946780",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/237173582992285/feed?fields=message,type,status_type&limit=25&until=1348763989"
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about the Page end-point [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_url($url) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
  $received_data = curl_exec( $ch );
  if($received_data){
  return $received_data;
  } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: If you tried this, you'll see it doesn't work for the URL in question.

Comment: And if you use the updated version, you're violating Facebook's terms of service. But it should work :)

Comment: I did try it, and it didn't work. As I mentioned, your edit makes it work, but violates Facebook's terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function get_facebook_id($facebookUrl)
 {
 $ch = curl_init($facebookUrl);
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; 
rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 $fbResponse = curl_exec( $ch );
if($fbResponse)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/"entity_id":"([0-9])+"/', $fbResponse, $matches))
    {
        $jsonObj = json_decode("{" . $matches[0] . "}");
        if($jsonObj)
        {
            $facebookId = $jsonObj->entity_id;
        }
    }
}
return $facebookId;
}
```

Comment: Hello Sem. Please describe what you have done to solve the question issue.