# unable to extract any facebook page images using php

Tags: php, facebook

I am implementing a link sharing feature in my website like facebook. When the user enters a url, it either finds the og:image tag, or uses some algorithm to find an appropriate image for the page. I also extract the title and the description.
I am doing this by getting file contents using `get_file_contents()` and then extracting stuff. It works on all pages exect fb pages. facebook doesnt let me use `get_file_contents()`.

Any way i can do this for facebook?

Comment: you mean [file_get_contents()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This violates facebook terms. But this is the answer to your question, facebook has a simple check to ensure that page should be opened by browser and thus we are mimicking it by setting useragent header.

Better to do it with cURL:
Here is a similar question [Facebook page feed doesn't work with php file_get_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213049/facebook-page-feed-doesnt-work-with-php-file-get-contents)

Just change the url of request. Or if you want to stick to file get contents function try setting parameters of user agent to it:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
  'method'=>"GET",
  'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
 )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```